# Definition of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

In many situations (problems as well as solutions) I encounter the complex number $i$ which many times is defined as $i^2=-1$ instead of $i=\sqrt{-1}$, since it is "more preferred". Does anyone know why? Is it because there are two solutions to the equation $x^2+a=0, \ \ a>0$?

Comment: In fact, there is no preference for $\sqrt{-1}$ nor $-\sqrt{-1}$, you can adopt one or the other without suffering too much consequences (except possibly some confusion). In analysis, I guess most people just adopt the convention that $i=\sqrt{-1}$, but in algebra the complex numbers is defined to be $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^{2}+1)$, so we don't have this problem. It is a matter of preference, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically this is because by $i^2=-1$ one introduces a new symbol by giving it new properties which make sense but writing down $\sqrt{-1}$ does not make sense until the symbol $i$ is defined (and also then it is ambigous since there is no "unique nonnegative solution"). Regarding your comment on two possible solutions: Using $i^2=-1$ it is then clear that also $(-i)^2 = -1$ and hence, there are two equally good possibilities for $i$.

Comment: There are two equally good possibilities for $i$ that are hard to distinguish before already defining them. But is there no way mathematicians can write down a set of statements that would uniquely define it as the one we usually think of now? Is it possible to establish two solutions of $x^2 = -1$ AND distinguish both of them without already assuming the existence of the one '$i$' ???